# Sum value of variable based on duplicate values of another variable

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I have the following table of ngrams:

```
require(data.table)
DT<-data.table(
  ngram=c("last","right","last year","last night", "right now", "right away"),
  Freq=c(6364,5163,988,835,1300,87),
  n=c(1,1,2,2,2,2),
  w1=c(22,37,22,22,37,37),
  w2=c(NA,NA,27,56,10,105),
  w3=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
  w4=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
)

> DT
        ngram Freq n w1  w2 w3 w4
1:       last 6364 1 22  NA NA NA
2:      right 5163 1 37  NA NA NA
3:  last year  988 2 22  27 NA NA
4: last night  835 2 22  56 NA NA
5:  right now 1300 2 37  10 NA NA
6: right away   87 2 37 105 NA NA
```

Where n denotes the type of ngram (e.g. 1=unigram, 2=bigram, etc), w1 through w4 are integer indexes of the words in each ngram, and Freq is the count of ngram occurrence in the data.

For each bigram, I need to sum the counts of all bigrams that have the same w1. I've tried

```
DT[.(2),n1:=sum(tabulate(match(Freq[duplicated(w1)],w1)))]
```

But it doesn't work:

```
> DT
        ngram Freq n w1  w2 w3 w4 n1
1:       last 6364 1 22  NA NA NA NA
2:      right 5163 1 37  NA NA NA NA
3:  last year  988 2 22  27 NA NA  0
4: last night  835 2 22  56 NA NA  0
5:  right now 1300 2 37  10 NA NA  0
6: right away   87 2 37 105 NA NA  0
```

What I need is:

```
> DT
        ngram Freq n w1  w2 w3 w4   n1
1:       last 6364 1 22  NA NA NA   NA
2:      right 5163 1 37  NA NA NA   NA
3:  last year  988 2 22  27 NA NA 1823
4: last night  835 2 22  56 NA NA 1823
5:  right now 1300 2 37  10 NA NA 1387
6: right away   87 2 37 105 NA NA 1387
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: With base functions, it would be something like `DT$n1 <- with(DT, ifelse(n==2, ave(Freq, interaction(n, w1), FUN=sum), NA))`... I don't know how to it with `data.table`  functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sumfun <- function(r) c(sum(DT[DT$w1==r[4] & DT$n==2,]$Freq))
DT$n1 <- NA
DT$n1[DT$n == 2] <- apply(DT[DT$n==2, ], 1, sumfun)


> DT
        ngram Freq n w1  w2 w3 w4   n1
1:       last 6364 1 22  NA NA NA   NA
2:      right 5163 1 37  NA NA NA   NA
3:  last year  988 2 22  27 NA NA 1823
4: last night  835 2 22  56 NA NA 1823
5:  right now 1300 2 37  10 NA NA 1387
6: right away   87 2 37 105 NA NA 1387
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach is to aggregate and then do an update join as follows:

```
DT[DT[n==2L, sum(Freq), by=.(n, w1)], n1 := V1, on=.(n, w1)]
```

Or another way of writing the same thing:

```
DT[n==2L, n1 := .SD[.SD[, sum(Freq), by=.(w1)], on=.(w1)]$V1]
```

GForce is turned on, so it should be fast enough. You can use `verbose=TRUE` within `[.data.table` to see log.

If you have any timings, do let us know which of the above is faster. I am betting on the 2nd one.

Comment: not a dumb qn actually. auto stuff are not always obvious to people. feel free to delete both comments